# How do you force vim to behave as a terminal app?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, vim

using vim via ssh on a machine with an x server running throws an X error. Specifically:

```
>vim
BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
Vim: Got X error
Vim: Finished.
```

This does not occur on my xorg-free server, so how can I force vim to behave as a console app?

[Edit]: I don't want to use X forwarding for a console app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the `-X` switch? This will disable the X integration features of Vim such as clipboard integration, so X is not needed to run it.

Comment: its a capital '-X' rather than the '-x' which edits an encrypted file, but it can be found by a simple vim --help. I just don't have my eyes in the right sockets today.

Comment: Yep, it's in `man vim`: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/vim/